# Как в ListView запретить вводить повторяющиеся элементы?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Пробую так:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in LW.Items)
{
    if (item.Content.Equals("Adobe Photoshop"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
    }
    else
    {
        Product AdobePH = new Product { Title = "Adobe Photoshop", Number = 1, NumPrice = 10, Price = 20, Placement = "в наличии" };
        ((ArrayList)LW.Resources["Product1"]).Add(AdobePH);
    }
}
```

Но выдает ошибку:

> **System.InvalidCastException**: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "merchandise.Product" к типу "System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem"."

Comment: Используйте привязку и работайте с коллекцией данных, а не с коллекцией элементов

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: @Виктор: Покажите, как эти самые элементы появляются в ListView.

Comment: @VladD В коде есть пример выше, там в else указано добавление.

Comment: @Виктор, оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не буду рассказывать вам сейчас про MVVM, чтобы его освоить вам нужно понять принцип действия привязок и источников данных для `ItemsControl`. Впрочем про привязки в моем ответе тоже ничего не будет.

Итак, думайте о данных, а не о контролах GUI. Не храните данные в контролах - заведите нормальную коллекцию:

```
List<Product> products;
```

Я в качестве примера заполняю ее в конструкторе окна и задаю как источник данных для контрола:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Заполним коллекцию тестовыми данными
    products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product { Title = "Microsoft Windows" },
        new Product { Title = "Microsoft Office" },
        new Product { Title = "Autodesk AutoCAD" },
        new Product { Title = "Corel Draw" },
        new Product { Title = "Autodesk 3ds Max" }
    };
    // Ссылку на коллекцию зададим как источник данных для ListView
    LV.ItemsSource = products;
}
```

Всё просто - у вас есть строго типизированная коллекция и в ней уже можно искать:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Проверим наличие продукта с заголовком "Adobe Photoshop"
    if (!products.Any(p => p.Title == "Adobe Photoshop"))
    {
        // Добавим его, если его нет
        products.Add(new Product { Title = "Adobe Photoshop" });
        // Скажем контролу, что нужно обновить данные из источника
        LV.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Всё! При нажатии на кнопку элемент добавится всего один раз.

Что интересно, если изменить тип коллекции на специализированный - вместо `List` использовать `ObservableCollection`, который умеет сообщать об изменениях самостоятельно, то нам не придется говорить контролу что пришло время обновиться, это будет происходить автоматически. В итоге это позволяет проектировать бизнес-логику в отрыве от визуального представления данных, что и лежит в основе паттерна MVVM.

Comment: спасибо! А можно как-нибудь изменить добавленный текст Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: @Виктор, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: допустим мы добавили элемент Adobe Photoshop. Как к примеру обратиться к нему кодом и изменить "Adobe Photoshop" допустим на "Adobe Dreamviewer" ?

Comment: Т.е. поменять текст в ячейке нашего ListView

Comment: @Виктор, абсолютно также - пусть в `p` нужный продукт, пишем `p.Title = "Adobe Illustrator";`, затем просим контрол обновить данные: `LV.Items.Refresh();`, если же ваш `Product` реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, то даже просить не надо - представление обновится автоматически

Comment: Если ничего не понятно - задайте отдельным вопросом